# fwupd-refresh.service failed

Tags: server, 20.04, bios, fwupd

I have VPS, and after checking `systemctl`, I noticed that my `fwupd-refresh.service` failed.

[image: terminal]

Can you explain the problem, and could you help to fix it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In some cases this error can be safely ignored. `fwupd-refresh.service` just executes `/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh` command and treats exit status `2` as success (see last 2 lines of `fwupd-refresh.service`). But `fwupdmgr` can also successfully exit with status `0`, which will be wrongfully interpreted by systemd as an error.

- `systemctl cat fwupd-refresh`:

  ```
  # /lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service
  [Unit]
  Description=Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd
  Documentation=man:fwupdmgr(1)
  After=network.target

  [Service]
  Type=oneshot
  CacheDirectory=fwupdmgr
  StandardError=null
  DynamicUser=yes
  RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_NETLINK AF_UNIX AF_INET AF_INET6
  SystemCallFilter=~@mount
  ProtectKernelModules=yes
  ProtectControlGroups=yes
  RestrictRealtime=yes
  SuccessExitStatus=2
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh
  ```
- `sudo /usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh`:

  ```
  ...
  Successfully downloaded new metadata: 0 local devices supported
  ```
- `echo $?`: `0`
- `man fwupdmgr`:

  ```
  EXIT STATUS
        Commands that successfully execute will return "0", but commands that have no actions but successfully execute will return "2".
  ```

Comment: Any idea why I'd get the following after `/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh`:

`Failed to connect to daemon: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.freedesktop.fwupd: Timeout was reached`

Comment: @MikeCiffone no, but these might be relevant: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/1805 https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/issues/4242

Comment: For anyone that experiences that timeout error: `apt upgrade fwupd.service` followed by `/usr/bin/fwupdmgr refresh` resolved it.

Comment: To expand on comment from @MikeCiffone - This worked for me as well. I recently upgraded to 22.04 and it appears a few packages were in the `hold` state so `apt` would not upgrade them. Explicitly using the package name in the upgrade command gives `apt` the "ok" to upgrade that package.

Comment: Why not `SuccessExitStatus=0 2`, since `fwupdmgr refresh` can return both 0 or 2 in case of (some definition of) success?

Answer (score 14):

In my own case (Ubuntu Server 20.04 with latest updates), `DynamicUser=no` provides quick&dirty solution.

First, run "systemctl edit fwupd-refresh" and enter:

```
[Service]
DynamicUser=no
```

Then, run "systemctl restart fwupd-refresh" and enjoy.

Comment: That works for me

Comment: Same here, this seems to have appeared in April 2022 (`journalctl -u fwupd-refresh` if you keep logs for long enough.)
Does anyone know what caused this? Thats probably a bug somewhere in ubuntu, isn't it?

Comment: Does not work on Debian 12 as of today

Answer (score 2):

**fwupd-refresh.service**
Loaded: masked

A service that is masked is disabled and can't be activated by an other unit (timers, targets, services...) that needs it or manually. It's the stronger version of disabling a service.

**fwupd-refresh.timer:** ...failed...unit fwupd-refresh is masked.

To change this:

```
sudo systemctl unmask fwupd-refresh
```

Then this:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && sudo systemctl start fwupd-refresh.service
systemctl list-units --failed
```

If fwupd-refresh is listed as failed then:

Uncomment `#DynamicUser=yes`  in  /lib/systemd/system/fwupd-refresh.service

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#DynamicUser=

Comment: Good stuff. I think you might want to add a sudo before: systemctl start fwupd-refresh.service

Answer (score 2):

I've solved my problem with it
https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/PluginFlag:legacy-bios

Simply adding "bios" at the end of this line `DisabledPlugins=test;invalid;bios`
in

```
/etc/fwupd/daemon.conf
```

Comment: Hm. Tried that, but nothing changed...

Comment: thanks, works for me on debian 12.